# Strange behavior in ember 1.13.*

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I have a controller `ApplicationController` with `controllerInt` and `controllerString` properties.

And I have a component `RedSquareComponent` with `componentInt` and `componentString` properties.

I bind `controllerInt` and `controllerString` to `componentInt` and `componentString` via hbs-template, `componentString=controllerString="VALUE FROM CONTROLLER"`.

In `RedSquareComponent` I also have `.on('init')` method which set `"SET ON INIT"` value to `componentString`.

I've added an action to component to handle click on some object (red square) and set some value (for example, 1) to `componentInt`.

But when this action works -- `componentString` also changes (I don't know why), and become equal to `"VALUE FROM CONTROLLER"`.

Is it a really expected behaviour?

The same code works fine on Ember 12.4, but I have checked it on several 13.* versions - it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyBedonik/a23ev98w/3/

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you just change `.on('init')` part to `.on('didInsertElement')` it will fix your problem.(that means it will update both controller and component `componentString` property to 'SET ON INIT'.)
But you should not change values on a parent that are rendered already is deprecated. so you will get deprecation warning.

To get more info about this issue/bug [follow this discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13823).

It's good to follow/understand below concepts.

1) Passing properties to component by default it is [two-way data binding](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/)
2) To update data always follow the Data Down Actions Up priniciple ([DDAU](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/how-ember-data-affects-data-down-actions-up/))